# Is this proof for the definition of the symmetric difference of two sets rigorous enough?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

My real analysis text asks me to show that the symmetric difference of two sets $A$ and $B$ is given by

> $D = (A \backslash B) \cup (B \backslash A)$

In the second part of the question, it then asks me to show that $D$ is also given by

> $D = (A \cup B) \backslash (A \cap B)$

I'm not sure my proof is rigorous enough. I just looked at the four possible cases,

1. $x \in A, x \in B$
2. $x \in A, x \notin B$
3. $x \notin A, x \in B$
4. $x \notin A, x \notin B$

and showed that each definition does give the symmetric difference in all of the four cases. I think that's all that's needed.

So for the first definition, $D = (A \backslash B) \cup (B \backslash A)$:

1. If $x \in A, x \in B$, then $x \notin A \backslash B$ or $x \notin B \backslash A$ by definition, so it's not in $(A \backslash B) \cup (B \backslash A)$ either. Therefore $x \notin D$.
2. If $x \in A, x \notin B$, then $x \in A \backslash B$, but $x \notin B \backslash A$, by definition, so $ x \in D$.
3. If $x \notin A, x \in B$, this is basically the same as point 2, so $x \in D$.
4. If $x \notin A, x \notin B$, then $x \notin A \backslash B$ and $x \notin B \backslash A$, by definition, so $x \notin D$.

For the second definition, $D = (A \cup B) \backslash (A \cap B)$:

1. If $x \in A, x \in B$, then $x \in (A \cup B)$ and $x \in (A \cap B)$, so by definition of the complement, $x \notin D$.
2. If $x \in A, x \notin B$, then $x \in (A \cup B)$, but $x \notin (A \cap B)$, so again by definition of the complement, $ x \in D$.
3. If $x \notin A, x \in B$, this is basically the same as point 2, so $x \in D$.
4. If $x \notin A, x \notin B$, then $x \in (A \cup B)$ and $x \notin (A \cap B)$, so $x \notin D$.

I think all of the steps above prove these definitions of $D$ in all possible cases, but is this rigorous enough (as in I haven't missed any cases), or is this not the right way to do these proofs?

(This question isn't technically homework since I'm just working through this book on the side, but I tagged it that way because I'm really just looking for hints at the moment)

Comment: @AWertheim Right I've seen that strategy before. I guess I'm confused on what two sets I'm showing equal for each definition. For the first definition, are the two sets I'm trying to show are equal 1) $D = (x \in A \text{ but } x \notin B) $ OR $(x \notin A \text{ but } x \in B)$ and 2) $D = (A \backslash B) \cup (B \backslash A)$ (so basically the definition in words/loose set notation, and the definition in terms of formal set notation)?

Comment: @AWertheim I guess that's what confused me. My book just says for part a) "Show that $D = (A \backslash B) \cup (B \backslash A)$. Then, for part b), it asks to show that $D$ is also given by the second definition. So for part a), what two sets am I'm trying to equate? (If that's more clear I'll edit it into the question)

Comment: @AWertheim The definition is just: "the symmetric difference of two sets $A$ and $B$ is the set $D$ of all elements that belong to either $A$ or $B$, but not both" That's how I came up with the four cases, and that's where I got that only cases 2 and 3 are in $D$.

Comment: I see. Then I think your proof is just fine. :)

Comment: @AWertheim Awesome, thanks. I guess I could also work part b) by equating the definition of $D$ given in the second part with the definition I proved in part a).

Comment: No problem - my apologies for my confusion. You certainly could, though I think the way you approached it is quite nice - it all comes down to taste.